# Load Memdisk with linux16 / initrd16 from Grub2 UEFI

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, syslinux

I need to load the Memdisk kernel from Grub2 in UEFI mode.

I don't know if this is possible, but I am getting an unexpected unidentified error.

I would like to know if it is possible and if so how to do it.

My menuentry/commands for Grub is as follows:

```
menuentry 'Hirens Boot 15.2' { 

  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 3a02381a-2bf7-4730-8e13-6d7640f9c60e
  set iso_path="/isos/Hirens.BootCD.15.2.iso"
        
  loopback loop ($root)$iso_path
      
  linux16 (loop)/HBCD/Boot/memdisk iso
  initrd16 /isos/Hirens.BootCD.15.2.iso
     
  }
```

The same menu entry is bootable without problems in BIOS mode.

Comment: Your menu entry is completely wrong. Not only are basic instructions missing and the files are in the wrong directory, you are also missing a dot between memdisk and iso. You may want to read this:
https://www.xmodulo.com/boot-iso-image-from-grub.html

Comment: Thank you. I meant to say my commands, I edited it.

Comment: I am pretty sure the mistake is in the `loop ($root)`. You might need to specify the partition in a different way than the UUID, like `loop (hd0,1)` for example

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot/Examples

Comment: No, those commands are loaded fine, the problem is when executing initrd16. Thank you for your input. I think Memdisk doesn't support UEFI, but I'm not sure. The same menu entry is bootable without problems in BIOS mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is going to work.

Hirens Boot CD 15.2 is from year 2012. Back then, UEFI was only just being introduced to the PC world, and most bootable tools still used the legacy BIOS way of doing things.

The `memdisk` utility expects to have the disk access functions of legacy BIOS available, so that it can extend them for use with a RAM-based disk image. In a system booting in UEFI mode, those legacy BIOS disk access functions are simply not available: indeed, the entire system runs in either 64- or 32-bit protected mode as opposed to the old DOS-compatible 16-bit mode that BIOS-based bootloaders start in.

`memdisk` is originally from the [Syslinux bootloader project](https://wiki.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php?title=MEMDISK), and as the linked webpage says:

> MEMDISK simulates a disk by claiming a chunk of high memory for the disk and a (very small - typically, 2K) chunk of low (DOS) memory for the driver itself, then hooking the INT 13h (disk driver) and INT 15h (memory query) BIOS interrupts.

In UEFI mode, DOS/BIOS concepts like low/high memory and BIOS interrupts INT 13h and INT 15h will not be applicable, so there will be no way for `memdisk` to do its job.

And even if you could get `memdisk` to work, the bootloader of the Windows PE environment that is used by the Hirens Boot CD image will also expect a legacy BIOS environment and most likely will fail to boot in a system that is booting in UEFI mode. And as far as I know, there is no standard way for GRUB or any other bootloader to switch a system from UEFI mode to legacy BIOS mode or vice versa.

Comment: Thanks for such a brilliant clarification.